# How to solve "Could not find goal generate" in plugin Swagger?

Tags: java, rest, maven, swagger

I have a problem with the automatic generation of my swagger interface. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-maven-plugin/README.md), I have configured my swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta as :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputFileName>${project.name}</outputFileName>
      <outputPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent</outputPath>
      <outputFormat>JSON</outputFormat>
      <resourcePackages>            
        <package>fr.inrae.sicpa.services</package>
      </resourcePackages>
      <prettyPrint>TRUE</prettyPrint>
      <sortOutput>TRUE</sortOutput>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Eclipse shows me a Maven Configuration Problem that I can't solve :

> Could not find goal 'generate' in plugin io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta:2.2.6 among available goals resolve

This problem appears on the line :

```
<phase>compile</phase>
```

I don't know what to do about this problem anymore. I tried to pass it to the **package** phase but then I get an error on the **goal** item.

At the end of this topic is my complete anonymized pom.xml

I thank you in advance for any help you can give me

Thierry

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.company.team.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProjectRest</artifactId>
  <name>MyProjectRest</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.5</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-jaxrs2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
    <!-- main -->
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <!-- test -->
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <extensions>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.wagon/wagon-ssh -->
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputFileName>${project.name}</outputFileName>
          <outputPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent</outputPath>
          <outputFormat>JSON</outputFormat>
          <resourcePackages>            
            <package>fr.inrae.sicpa.services</package>
          </resourcePackages>
          <prettyPrint>TRUE</prettyPrint>
          <sortOutput>TRUE</sortOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>    
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-profile-target</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireActiveProfile>
                  <profiles>prod,rec,test</profiles>
                  <all>false</all>
                </requireActiveProfile>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>  
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin -->
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*.json</include>
          <include>*.properties</include>
          <include>*.wadl</include>
          <include>*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>rec</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>rec</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-rec</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>master-rec</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>upload-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
                  <url>scp://user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/wars/autodeploy</url>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>slave-rec</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>upload-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
                  <url>scp://user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/wars/autodeploy</url>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/rec</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>*.json</include>
              <include>*.properties</include>
              <include>*.wadl</include>
              <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>prod</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-prod</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>enforce-prod-no-snapshot</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>enforce</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <rules>
                    <requireReleaseVersion/>
                    <requireReleaseDeps/>
                  </rules>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/wagon-maven-plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>master-prod</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>upload-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
                  <url>scp://user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/wars/autodeploy</url>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>slave-prod</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>upload-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}.${project.packaging}</fromFile>
                  <url>scp://user@xx.xx.xx.xx:/data/wars/autodeploy</url>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/prod</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>*.json</include>
              <include>*.properties</include>
              <include>*.wadl</include>
              <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>test</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>*.json</include>
              <include>*.properties</include>
              <include>*.wadl</include>
              <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <warName>${project.name}</warName>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Java\wars\autodeploy</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: hello, no one have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
<goal>generate</goal>
```

with

```
<goal>resolve</goal>
```